# Managing multiple fragments next to each other

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am currently working on a tablet app which has 1 main activity. In this activity there are 6 buttons which represent the main menu. When clicked a fragment opens, which contains a submenu. When a submenu item is clicked another fragment is opened.

At this point I have 2 active fragments in 1 activity.

My problem is that when I click a new 'main menu' button just 1 of the 2 activities closes, the first one that was opened. I think it works like a list, first in / first out when the third activity is opened.

When I use replace and only one fragment is active there is no problem, it is closed and the other one opens.

How do I manage more than 2 fragments?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the awnser myself, I have to give every Fragment a name and add them to the backstack.

```
ft.addToBackStack("fragmentname");
```

When a 'main menu item' is clicked I remove all fragments from the backstack:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

When I wish to selectively remove fragments from the backstack when I open een sub menu I use:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack ("film", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

I hope this helps some people facing the same problem.

Kind regards